# starting OCR project in android studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to make simple OCR project on android studio, but I have problem getting started, as a don't know if I added the tess-two correctly or not, I followed this site: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/840623/Android-Character-Recognition
I just want the simplest way to make it and a simple way to install NDK  correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already build the jar files from the library. Follow [my gist](https://gist.github.com/deepak786/60adae3fe4eaacf8b98c) to download and use the library:

> 1. Download the tesseract library from the following link named libs.zip. https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fwqz88sck3xlk4/libs.zip?dl=0
> 2. Extract the zip folder.
>
>    - If you are using Eclipse then copy all the files and folders from libs folder to libs folder in your project.
>    - if you are using Android Studio then Copy all th e folders from libs folder to src/main/jniLibs folder in your project and copy the
>        classes.jar to libs folder.
> 3. Add image containing text inside your downloads folder and give the name a.png.
> 4. create folder named tessdata inside the assets folder in your project.
> 5. download the file named eng.traineddata from the below link and copy it inside the tessdata folder created in the 4th step.
>      https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xdnfzp8qsy4ll9/eng.traineddata?dl=0
> 6. add permission to manifest "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
> 7. copy and paste the below code.
>
> ```
> try{
>   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/download/a.png");
>
>   // _path = path to the image to be OCRed
>   ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/download/a.png");
>   int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
> ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
>
>   int rotate = 0;
>
>   switch (exifOrientation) {
>   case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
>       rotate = 90;
>       break;
>   case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
>       rotate = 180;
>       break;
>   case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
>       rotate = 270;
>       break;
>   }
>
>   if (rotate != 0) {
>       int w = bitmap.getWidth();
>       int h = bitmap.getHeight();
>
>       // Setting pre rotate
>       Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
>       mtx.preRotate(rotate);
>
>       // Rotating Bitmap & convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
>       bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
>   }
>   bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
>   TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
>
>   // tesseract reads language from tesseract folder, create it if not exists.
>   File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/tesseract/tessdata");
>   if(!f.exists()){
>       f.mkdirs();
>   }
>
>   // copy the eng lang file from assets folder if not exists.
>   File f1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/tesseract/tessdata/eng.traineddata");
>   if(!f1.exists()){
>       InputStream in = getAssets().open("tessdata/eng.traineddata");
>       FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(f1);
>         byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
>         int len;
>         while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
>           fout.write(buf, 0, len);
>         }
>         in.close();
>         fout.close();
>   }
>
>   // DATA_PATH = Path to the storage and data path must contain tessdata subdirectory
>   // lang = for which the language data exists, usually "eng"
>   // Eg. baseApi.init("/mnt/sdcard/tesseract/tessdata/eng.traineddata", "eng");
>   baseApi.init(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/tesseract", "eng");
>
>   baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
>   String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
>   baseApi.end();
>   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), recognizedText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>   System.out.println("Text is>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + recognizedText);
> }catch(Exception e){
>   e.printStackTrace();
> }
> ```